# How to query "OR" on one field for multiple values in cassandra with java

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using `Cassandra` query with java to find out all the students with names **John** and **James** who have got 80 marks.

My Entity is:

```
@Table(value="student")
public class Student{

@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;
private double marks;

//getters and setters

}
```

Query for finding the names(John and James) with 80 marks is:

```
Statement query = QueryBuilder.select().from("keyspace", "student").allowFiltering()
                .where(QueryBuilder.eq("name", "John")).and(QueryBuilder.eq("marks", 80));
```

Query Execution:

```
cassandraTemplate.getSession().execute(query);
```

I tried using `QueryBuilder.in` but seems like we can use it only with primary keys.

**How do I check for both John and James at once and fetch the record?**

Comment: You have a big problem with your data model that will bite you as your data grow. `.allowFiltering` will require the Cassandra to scan all your data searching for your condition

Comment: How should I make the query without .allowFiltering?
When I tried it without .allowFiltering it gave an exception :com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

Comment: You need to model the data structures around the queries you're doing. This is how Cassandra works.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @AlexOtt